# In what module is shapefile defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to run [this example](https://pythonhosted.org/Python%20Shapefile%20Library/). It fails on the first line:

```
$ python3
>>> import shapefile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shapefile'
```

Apparently `shapefile` is not in the standard library. When I [search in PyPi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=shapefile) I get results, but in the first result no `import shapefile` is provided, so it's unclear if this will work for me.

Am I missing something here, and should I just try all matches from the PyPi search without any reasoning? I'm a bit lost here...

Comment: how about the second result? https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/
Google point me to that instead of the first one

Comment: Check the date of your link (2010). It is quite outdated. The linked library `pyshp` seems to be the correct one (probably got renamed in the last 9 years), as it also has the same author listed as in your linked document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the page you're looking at is maybe out of date.

First run `pip install pyshp` on the command line. Then `import shapefile` in the Python prompt.

This works for me on Python 3.5.6.

https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/

Comment: Thanks! I'm new into gis, so I don't know what I'm doing. I noticed installing `shp-way` with pip also worked, but is hardly any documentation. I'll try this.

Answer (score 1):

To run `import shapefile` you need to install the `pyshp` library.

Need to do `pip install pyshp` and then run `import shapefile`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the version of pyshp you have installed.
Earlier versions of pyshp don't import shapefile correctly.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyshp==2.3.0
```